# Dwolla OAuth giving Invalid Client Id

Tags: c#, dwolla

I'm trying to use the Dwolla OAuth feature, so I send the user to the following url:

**https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/v2/authenticate?client_id=mydwollakey&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost//Payment/OAuthResponse&scope=send%7Ctransactions**

The first time I send them there, it takes them to a Dwolla login page. Once they enter in their username and password and click Login, it gives them:

**We were unable to authenticate you with Dwolla: access_denied Invalid client ID.**

The client id is my Dwolla Key, which I'm sure is valid, as I'm able to make another call with it (register user) just fine.

After that, every time they go back to the url, it no longer takes them to the login page, it returns "We were unable to authenticate you with Dwolla: access_denied - Invalid client ID." right away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ended up being that my dwolla key has a / and + in it, and I needed to UrlEncode it before passing it in the querystring.

Comment: good catch here! worth noting that you need UrlEncode anything that is passed in the querystring, including the OAuth tokens (?oauth_token=) when that contains an illegal char.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your key has been associated with the correct permissions. I believe OAuth2 refers to this as "scope".

Comment: No luck, I have all permissions checked for my application. The first time I try to make the OAuth request, it takes me to a Dwolla login page. Once I enter in my username and password and click Login, it gives me "We were unable to authenticate you with Dwolla: access_denied - Invalid client ID.". After that, every time I try to make the OAuth request, it no longer takes me to the login page, it returns "We were unable to authenticate you with Dwolla: access_denied - Invalid client ID." right away.

Comment: My client_id has a / and also a + in it, could that be the issue since it's being passed in the url querystring?